# Detect where in the process we are in?

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I have an interesting question if someone can help me to think up a solution. 
I spawn 2 separate processes, A and B. Think them as a Queue waiting for work

1. A is being filled and do something
2. A is done and pass onto B
3. B do something and finish

How do I detect where in the process we are in using Java? And how I would stop this process where ever we are at?

Thanks!

Comment: You use the work "processes".  Do you mean threads?

Comment: When you say "stop the process" are you talking about more than `System.exit(0)`?

Answer (score 1):

In pure Java, you would have memory variables that are accessed by both threads, so they can communicate. You would need to make them synchronized or use semaphores to make sure only one thread at a time is modifying the information in the variable.

Other languages have the concept of actors, which implement more robust inter-thread communication by passing messages. Look into Scala - it's built on top of Java. Or the akka library, which has Scala and Java versions.

If you like thinking about this stuff, try the book *Seven Languages in Seven Weeks* by the Pragmatic Programmers.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `currentStage` variable and update stage at different locations in your code. Also save your "registers". By this I mean save your local variables that you care about. Serialize objects and perhaps place them in a database.

Then if you quit and restart, you go to the last saved stage and restore the corresponding objects from the database.

Answer (score 0):

To follow the process you would need another Thread (C) that can read status information outputted by A & B and that can be asked by A & B if they should continue.

For instance, create a `ProcessFollower` interface with 2 methods:

1. void updateStatus (String)
2. boolean shouldStop ()

C can implement this interface and pass itself when calling A, A passed the reference to `ProcessFollower` (C) to B. Each time the status changes A and B call `updateStatus` and on each occasion (e.g. each loop iteration) they check `shouldStop`(); if false they simply return or such.